# Deleting characters as long as button is pressed

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

How can I do deleting characters with certain interval as long as button pressed? Have tried to use LongPressGestureRecognizer, but got infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change things like that, you will have to actually implement your own text editor.  Most default text editors react on keypress events which are auto repeated by the OS after it has been held down for a time.  You can change your OS settings to minimize the delay but that works on everything system-wide for all keypresses (and only for you).  If you want to change the behavior of your specific text editor, you will have to implement your own text editor that reacts exactly on keydown/keyup events and handles the repeating internally through a timer.